# Can't get rid of the word TRUE is result cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How do I replace TRUE with "past due", if conditions are in fact true. For example: `IF(AND(TODAY()>C5),ISBLANK(B5),"<-- past due"))`

currently `TRUE` is displaying in the cell, but I want `<-- past due` to display.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `"past due"` the second parameter of the IF function. Also, the closing parentheses after `>C5` is misplaced. It belongs after the second parameter of the AND function:

```
=IF(AND(TODAY()>C5,ISBLANK(B5)),"past due")
```

If you don't provide the parameters to the IF function, as was the case in your original formula, Excel returns the result of the function, which is either TRUE or FALSE.